# Scheduling Book with day and date on each page

Tags: microsoft-excel

I wanted to create a simple Scheduling Book for my business, Each page should have the Day, Month, Date and Year (e.g. Wednesday, June 25, 2022). on the top of the page.
So I can print them later in a logbook sort of thing.

I am trying to figure out a formula on excel but seems no luck

Your help would be appreciated
cheers

Comment: There's not much to go here, but assuming you have the date in `A1` then `=A1+1` should give you the next day

Comment: You may want to consider an alternative approach, as the number of tabs/pages will eventually become an issue. I suggest just adding an additional column with date/time to the rest of what you already have as a scheduling book in ONE page. Filtering the date will give you the daily schedule that you want. One bonus is filtering this one page for a customer name to see when you last interacted with them would be a lot easier than going though a 100 pages to find that last customer interaction. There will probably be more. Good luck.

Comment: Do you mean the header and footer?